# OLS model will not run, and spits out Error in model.frame.default

Tags: r, dataframe, linear-regression, economics

I have just started coding in R, starting last week and am trying to make a linear model, but have run into two errors. First I tried to run a regression using

```
reg1 <- lm(Ex ~ Im)
```

Ex and Im are exports and imports to the US by country, and the matrices are exactly the same in size. Below is the code that it shows me.

```
  Error in model.frame.default(formula = Ex ~ Im, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : invalid type (list) for variable 'Ex'
```

I then tried to see if making a data frame for all the variables would allow it to work.

```
Im <- data.frame(Im, Im = unlist(Im), row.names = NULL)
Ex <- data.frame(Ex, Ex = unlist(Ex), row.names = NULL)
er <- data.frame(er, er = unlist(er), row.names = NULL)
FTA <- data.frame(FTA, FTA = unlist(FTA), row.names = NULL)
NAFTA <- data.frame(NAFTA, NAFTA = unlist(NAFTA), row.names = NULL)
t <- data.frame(t, t = unlist(t), row.names = NULL)
u <- data.frame(u, u = unlist(u), row.names = NULL) 
d <- data.frame(D, d=unlist(D), row.names = NULL)
FBP <- data.frame(FBP, FBP = unlist(FBP), row.names = NULL)
```

My third attempt was to merge data sets so that I could then run a regression qith merged data sets, which I thought might fix it.

```
IE <- merge(NAFTA, FTA, by=c(Year, Year))
```

R then spit out

```
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : object 'Year' not found
```

I have no idea what to doin order to make the code work.

Below I have put all of my code in case that is helpful for someone.

````
Import datasets
```{r}
 Im = read.csv("Imports2.csv")
 Ex = read.csv("Exports2.csv")
 er = read.csv("erfinished2.csv")
 FTA = read.csv("FTA2.csv")
 NAFTA = read.csv("NAFTA2.csv")
 t = read.csv("TData_US2.csv")
 u = read.csv("Unemployment.csv")
 D = read.csv("DtoDC.csv")
 FBP = read.csv("Fiscal_Balance_US 3.csv")
 ```
````

input NAs
    `{r}
    u[u == ""] <- NA
    t[t == ""] <- NA
    er[er == ""] <- NA
    FBP[FBP == ""] <- NA
    NAFTA[NAFTA == ""] <- NA
    Im[Im == ""] <- NA
    Ex[Ex == ""] <- NA
    FTA[FTA == ""] <- NA`

    view dataset
    `{r}
    View(Im)
    View(Ex)
    View(er)
    View(FTA)
    View(NAFTA)
    View(t)
    View(u)
    View(D)
    View(FBP)`

````
log distance
```{r}
lnd = data.frame(D$Capital,log(D$Air_Distance_.miles.))
View(lnd)
ls() 
```
make data frame
```{r}
Im <- data.frame(Im, Im = unlist(Im), row.names = NULL)
Ex <- data.frame(Ex, Ex = unlist(Ex), row.names = NULL)
er <- data.frame(er, er = unlist(er), row.names = NULL)
FTA <- data.frame(FTA, FTA = unlist(FTA), row.names = NULL)
NAFTA <- data.frame(NAFTA, NAFTA = unlist(NAFTA), row.names = NULL)
t <- data.frame(t, t = unlist(t), row.names = NULL)
u <- data.frame(u, u = unlist(u), row.names = NULL)
d <- data.frame(D, d=unlist(D), row.names = NULL)
FBP <- data.frame(FBP, FBP = unlist(FBP), row.names = NULL)
 ```
merge
```{r}
IE <- merge(NAFTA, FTA, by=c(Year, Year))
```
````

Comment: I think it would be nice to have a better example. What does `str(Im)` and `str(Ex)` tell you? Look at `head(Im)` and `head(Ex)`. I would assume that you have to give vectors to the lm function. Something like `lm(Ex$column_name ~ Im$column_name)` should work.

Comment: I ran it and I think you are right, it spat out:                              data.frame': 137088 obs. of  65 variables:
 $ Year                : int  1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 ...
 $ Greenland           : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 11.6 13.1 9.4 ...
 $ Canada              : num  69006 68253 71085 81398 87953 ...
Is their a way to run a regression for all of the vectors simultaniously, instead of doing it by hand?

Comment: Then try something like:
`lm(Ex$USA ~ Im$Mexico + Im$Canada + Im$Greenland + and so on`.